# Nesting appSettings with the file attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, appsettings

I'm trying to pull off an inheritance chain of appSetting sections (VS2010 C#)

Given this,

Base.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="basekey" value="basevalue"/>
</appSettings>
```

Derived.config

```
<appSettings file="Base.config">
    <add key="derivedkey" value="derivedvalue" />
</appSettings>
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="Derived.config">
        <add key="mykey" value="myvalue" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This line:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["derivedkey"]
```

Throws exception:

> Unrecognized attribute 'file'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (...\Derived.config line 1)

It appears that App.config can successfully "file" over to Derived.config, but Derived.config is unable to "file" over to Base.config because "file" suddenly becomes an unknown attribute.

It's a little circular/confusing to me since the "file" attribute in App.config must be recognized successfully in order to reach Derived.config, where the same "file" attribute is suddenly unknown.

Comment: @jonperl It's been a few months but for the record, I think this is simply a limitation with the config reader. Unfortunately I ended up restructuring my config files with the limitation in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just not alllowed. You can not specify another external AppSetting file from within the first external AppSetting file.

Comment: Alternatively you may use configSource attribute instead of first file attribute which will work for you I guess. The only limitation is that you can't go to an upper folder with configSource attribute.